# How to trigger event only when i click table row but not when i click table row element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here i am adding a class to row which i am clicking on. the issue i am facing is  i have a text box and dropdown field inside a table. but when i click on textbox or dropdown to input value the function is getting triggered. what i exactly want to do is when i click on the row then the class should added, when i click on the element inside the table row the class should not get added.

how can i do this?

here is what i have done.

```
<script>
var tabRow = $('.extab tbody tr');    
    tabRow.on('click',function(){
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    })
</script>



<table class="extab">
<tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>2</th></tr>
<tbody>
    <tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><select><option val="1">DSD</option><option val="2">FSJ</option><option val="3">MSD</option></select></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><select><option val="1">DSD</option><option val="2">FSJ</option><option val="3">MSD</option></select></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><select><option val="1">DSD</option><option val="2">FSJ</option><option val="3">MSD</option></select></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><select><option val="1">DSD</option><option val="2">FSJ</option><option val="3">MSD</option></select></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr> 
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you are technically clicking the table row when you click anything inside of it. There are ways to do what you are asking but why would you want to only add the class if the tr element is clicked and nothing else? I see you are adding class selected... what is the intention of this class? to highlight the row? when would the user just select the row and nothing inside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check to see if what is clicked on is the cell or the input with the events target

```js
var taBody = $('.extab tbody') 
taBody.on('click', 'tr', function (evt) {
  if($(evt.target).is('td')) {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  }
})
```

```css
.selected{
  background: red;
}
td{
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="extab">
<tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>2</th></tr>
<tbody>
    <tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><select><option val="1">DSD</option><option val="2">FSJ</option><option val="3">MSD</option></select></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><select><option val="1">DSD</option><option val="2">FSJ</option><option val="3">MSD</option></select></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><select><option val="1">DSD</option><option val="2">FSJ</option><option val="3">MSD</option></select></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><select><option val="1">DSD</option><option val="2">FSJ</option><option val="3">MSD</option></select></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr> 
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have added padding on `td` for better illustration. And this works perfectly fine as you need.

```js
var tabRow = $('.extab tbody tr');    
tabRow.on('click',function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected');
})
$('.extab tbody tr td *').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

```css
.selected{
  background: red;
}
td{
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="extab">
<tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>2</th></tr>
<tbody>
    <tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><select><option val="1">DSD</option><option val="2">FSJ</option><option val="3">MSD</option></select></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><select><option val="1">DSD</option><option val="2">FSJ</option><option val="3">MSD</option></select></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><select><option val="1">DSD</option><option val="2">FSJ</option><option val="3">MSD</option></select></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><select><option val="1">DSD</option><option val="2">FSJ</option><option val="3">MSD</option></select></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr> 
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like :

```
$('.extab tbody tr td *').click(function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); });
```

---

```js
var tabRow = $('.extab tbody tr');    
    tabRow.on('click',function(){
        console.log('row clicked');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });

$('.extab tbody tr td *').click(function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); });
```

```css
tr td {
 padding: 5px;
 background-color : red;
}

tr.selected td {
  background-color : blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="extab">
<tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>2</th></tr>
<tbody>
    <tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><select><option val="1">DSD</option><option val="2">FSJ</option><option val="3">MSD</option></select></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><select><option val="1">DSD</option><option val="2">FSJ</option><option val="3">MSD</option></select></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><select><option val="1">DSD</option><option val="2">FSJ</option><option val="3">MSD</option></select></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><select><option val="1">DSD</option><option val="2">FSJ</option><option val="3">MSD</option></select></td><td><input type="text"></td></tr> 
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: would this prevent the drop down from being selected?

Comment: @floor , No it not , please check the added snippet

Comment: I see you can select the menu, but if I was to add an on click event to the menu or on change would that still work?

Comment: @floor , it would ignore the clicks only of the elements within td